# Show that any continuous $f:[0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]$ has a fixed point $\zeta$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Be a continuous function $f:[0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]$.

Show that there is a $\zeta \in [0,1]$ with $f(\zeta)=\zeta$ ($\zeta$ is called fixed point).

Consider the function $g:[0,1] \rightarrow [-1,1]$, $g(x):= f(x)-x$.

$g$ is continuous.

Because of $f(0),f(1) \in [0,1]$ is $g(0)\geq0$ and $g(1)\leq 0$.

Because $f(0)$ has a value between $0$ and $1$, $f(0)\geq 0$.

$g(0) = f(0)-0= f(0) \geq 0 - 0 = 0$.

Because $f(1)$ has a value between $0$ and $1$, $ f(1) \leq 1 $.

$g(1)=f(1)-1 \leq 1 - 1 = 0$ $\Leftrightarrow g(0)\geq 0$ and $g(1)\leq 0 $

After the IVT: $\exists \zeta \in [0,1]:g(\zeta)=0 \Leftrightarrow f(\zeta) = \zeta $

$\zeta$ is a fixed point of $f$. $\Box$

My questions are:

Is this proof done in the correct way or have I missed something?

Is there something I can improve?

Comment: It's OK for me. Just try to write it on a more elegant way.

Comment: The "In other words" paragraph is superfluous. Don't say **the** fixed point, there may be more than one. Rest depends on exact statement of IVT, may need to separate out cases where one or both of $g(0)$ or $g(1)$ is $0$. Overall good.

Comment: Ok,thx, I have replaced the "the" by the "a".

Comment: The monkish version of this problem: http://mindyourdecisions.com/blog/2007/11/20/game-theory-tuesdays-a-brain-teaser-and-related-trivia/#.VFsrUVotP0M.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, your proof is pretty much correct. I might change it slightly so that it's presented better.

> Let $f:[0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]$ be a continuous function. Show that there is a $\zeta \in [0,1]$ with $f(\zeta)=\zeta$ (that is, show that there exists some **fixed point** $\zeta$).

Consider the function $g:[0,1] \rightarrow [-1,1]$ defined by $g(x):= f(x)-x$. Note that since $f$ is continuous and polynomials are continuous, $g$ is also continuous.

Now observe that since $f(0)\in [0,1] \implies f(0) \ge 0$, we have:
$$
g(0) = f(0)-0= f(0) \geq 0
$$
Likewise, since $f(1) \in [0,1] \implies f(1) \leq 1$, we have:
$$
g(1)=f(1)-1 \leq 1 - 1 = 0
$$
Thus, since $g(1) \leq 0 \leq g(0)$, we know by IVT that $\exists \zeta \in [0,1]$ such that $g(\zeta)=0 \iff f(\zeta) = \zeta $. Hence, $\zeta$ is a fixed point of $f$, as desired. $\Box$

Answer (score 2):

The basic argument is a correct one, but there is at least one incorrect statment, which is "$g(x)=f(x)-x\iff f(x)=x$" which isn't what you meant. You were trying to define $g$ and then separately say $g(x)=0\iff f(x)=x$.

Comment: I have dropped this line.